# Eclipse debugger - not work suddenly ( waiting for debugger forever)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I have coded Android by Eclipse IDE for such a long time. However Eclipse is working fine, and can not debug suddenly.
The message is "... is waiting for debugger to attach." and keep that screen forever.
I have tried to add android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP to Manifest file but nothing is changed.

I realize that in Log cat mentioned "waiting for debugger at port 8100" while in console, the message is "Attempting to connect .... port 8609". Anything's wrong with this?

Help me, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways to get around this:

- Unplug then plug in again usb-cable ( if you're connecting with usb port)
- Restart device
- Restart java

I've met this case so many times and still have no idea why, but after doing some above tricks, it works :o really weird Android :(

Comment: I have tried to restart java, restart my computer also. :(. It does not work also. And all of my project do not run debug ( run application is ok, but debug is not)

Comment: @ndnguyen try to kill adb (./adb kill-server command ) and restart your device ?

Comment: Thanks. It works after removing or restarting thing many times.

Answer (score 0):

Once try to clean the project, open the project in debug view, check once the breakpoints and try to debug again. If not restart the eclispe once. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Run debug app once then again try using run app...this will do.